# How browser's identify login forms?

Tags: html, authentication, browser

I'm trying to find out: how browsers identify login forms in different sites?

Doesn't matter if I'm acessing my GMail account or some personal project, IE/Firefox always knows that that page contains login info.

Do they conclude that simply searching for input types = password or there is some cookie information involved?

Thank you in advance.

Filipe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No only do they look for type=password they will also look for common input names for usernames and passwords.

For example most browsers will detect the following field names as login information.

```
<input name="login" type=text>
<input name="user" type=text>
<input name="username" type=text>
<input name="passwd" type="password">
<input name="pass" type="password">
<input name="password" type="password">
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere for popular browsers like IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari?

Comment: I don't know if it is documented but each of these have worked for me in the past.

Comment: Google Chrome FireFox and Safari seems only to look for type="password". I have a Problem with the MS browsers (IE and Edge). The don't store the credentials (note the browsers are configured correct). I now have changed the names according to your posting, but IE and Edge still don't save the credentials :-( Any Ideas?

Comment: I have find the reason, why IE11 and Edge don't have worked: IE11 and only are triggered, when the files are embedded in a <form> tag, whereby the other browsers also work without the <form> tag

Answer (score 6):

They look for input type=password.