# How does Password Managers (in browsers) detect user & password fields, and how to force this detection?

Tags: input, passwords, field

I'm trying to understand how does password managers to detect user & password field in forms.
I guess that the password field is detected by looking for a input[type="password"], and the user field is the direct previous input (hidden, text, email, etc...)

/***** EDITED ****/

Confirmed, for example:
I have two forms

F1= name,email,pass

F2= email,name,pass

So, I save my password in the first form, the PM saves "email" and "pass".

Then, the second form is filled with the value of email in the field name.

/***** END EDITED ****/

But this produces too many bugs, and these are very commons, even in some famous sites and frameworks.

There are some way to explicitly specific which fields should be saved?
I didnt find any info in internet.

I only find this propose: http://www.mypico.org/documents/2014-StajanoETAL-api.pdf but is not implemented yet (and maybe never)

Comment: There is an answer for https://stackoverflow.com/q/1976765/6607497 already