# Autofill (login credentials) don’t work in IE11 and Edge

Tags: html, authentication, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I develop a public portal with asp.net core 2.2, where users have to login to be able to rate.
If the user want to rate and is not logged in, a bootstrap modal (see below) login form is showed.

Problem:
Google Chrome (desktop and mobile), FireFox and Safari mobile are working as expected:
After first login, the browser ask, if the credential should be stored in the browser and the credentials are filled automatically by next login.

In IE11 and Edge, this don’t work (the browsers don’t ask, if the credentials should be stored and don’t fill it automatically).
Notes:

- The browsers are configured correct for credentials (under autofill,
  "save password", and "save form entries" are activated).
- IE11 and Edge store credentials for other sites

It seems as GC , FF and safari looks for input type="password" what then triggers the  save credentials.
It seems as this **don’t** work for IE and Edge.

By my search, I have found this thread:
[How browser's identify login forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976765/how-browsers-identify-login-forms)

I then have changed the id to the password input to “password” and added name = “password”.
To the nickname, I have added name = “username”.
(note: this is not needed for FF and GC).

Unfortunately, this don’t help....

**What do I have to change, to let the credentials also store from IE11 and Edge?**

Code to login:

```
<div class="modal fade;" id="BenutzerAnmeldung">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Anmelden als Benutzer</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div style="font-size: 14px"> Um diese Funktion auszuführen, müssen Sie als Benutzer angemeldet sein. </div>
      <hr /> 
      <div id=Status style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size:16px">
        Aktueller Status: Nicht angemeldet
      </div>
      <hr /> 

      <div style="font-size: 16px"> Ihre Anmeldedaten:</div>
      <div class="form-group row" style="font-size: 14px ; padding-top:10px">
        <label for="TBNickname" style="width: 100px; font-size: 14px; padding-left: 15px; padding-top:5px ">Nickname:</label>
        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="TBNickname" placeholder="Ihr Nickname..." style="width: 150px; font-size: 14px; padding-top:10px ">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" style="font-size: 14px ; padding-top:10px">
        <label for="TBPasswort" style="width: 100px; font-size: 14px; padding-left: 15px; padding-top:5px ">Passwort:</label>
        <input  name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Ihr Passwort..." style="width: 150px; font-size: 14px; padding-top:10px ">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="BenutzerAnmelden" style="width:135px; margin:5px;">Anmelden</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" style="width:135px; margin:5px;">Schliessen</button>
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="BenutzerNeuErfassen" style="width:280px; margin:5px;">Ganz neu als Benutzer erfassen</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your question or why, but I do know I typically downvote a question when the asker doesn't [read the tags they use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhMrE.png) for their question... it's possible whoever downvoted your question did so for similar reasons.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by DE, but it's also a complete guess that whoever downvoted you did so because of an assumption of lack of searching somewhere. Don't assume downvotes are without reason... you can often guess with enough experience when a downvote is made out of malice but typically downvotes received within a few hours of posting a question are made for good reason. Finally, comments are not required for votes of any kind, and for good reason. It would only serve to create noise and encourage retaliation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant SO not DE (I work with DevExpress, therefore the typo -;) And... if you don't see a reason to downvote, there IS no reason. But this discussion don't make sense...

Comment: Just because you don't see a reason for a downvote doesn't mean there isn't one. It just means the downvoter chose not to share their reason or, as previously stated, chose not to forego their anonymity.

Comment: As I wrote.. this discussion don' make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason, why it don't have worked in IE11 and Edge:
I simply have embedded the code additonally in a `<form>` tag and now it works....

So my conclusion:
**It seems as IE11 and Edge only triggers the the "save credentials dialog", if the fields are in ebmbeded in `<form>` tag, whereby this is no needed for GC and FF.**

Comment: Glad to hear you have solved the problem. Congratulation. Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT: Done (marked as answer). Maybe you want to upvote the question, as it was - for whatever reason - downvoted short after posting.